# Sprite bouncing off the sides - bottom & right side work but not top and left

Tags: android, sprite

i'm trying to create a wrap around method to make a sprite bounce of each side of the screen. I've got the bottom and right side working but can't seem to figure out why it won't off the top or the left. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public void wrapAround(){
    wrapAround = true;
    //Code to wrap around   
    if (x < 0) x = x + gameView.getWidth(); //increment x whilst not off screen
    if (x >= gameView.getWidth()){ //if gone of the right sides of screen

        xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
    }
    if (x <= gameView.getWidth())
    {
        xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
    }

    if (y < 0) y = y + gameView.getHeight();//increment y whilst not off screen
    if (y >= gameView.getHeight()){//if gone of the bottom of screen


        ySpeed = (ySpeed * -1);
    }
    if (y <= gameView.getHeight())
    {
        ySpeed = (ySpeed * -1);
    }
```

Comment: The sprite just wiggles back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs a lot of clarification.

```
if (x < 0) x = x + gameView.getWidth(); //this code executes only when x IS off screen on the left side, which means you want to move it to the right size. No bouncing is implied here.
```

The following reverses the velocity of the sprite if it is off the screen on the right side, but if the function wrap around is called again right afterwards, the velocity would reverse again making it wiggle back and forth when hitting left or bottom wall.

```
if (x >= gameView.getWidth()){ //if gone of the right sides of screen

    xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
}
if (x <= gameView.getWidth())
{
    xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
}
```

I have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve, because half your code attempts to wrap an item around, while the other half attempts to make it bounce.